# Finding 3D coordinates from corresponding points in stereo images in EMGU

Tags: c#, opencv, 3d

I know there is a function in OpenCV to do this called *triangulatePoints* [1], but I have not found a similar one in EMGU (an OpenCV wrapper).

I would also accept one from another library, as long as it is implementable in C#.

[1] http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints